# Reverse command-line arguments (C)

Tags: c

The overall gist of the program is to accept a command-line argument and for each string to print out backwards with variable length.

For example:

```
$ ./reversecommand hello 102
dnammocesrever/. olleh 201
```

I am having difficulty in implementing the thought process into code (e.g. with hello below). Any thoughts?

```
argc[0] ./reversecommand 
argc[1] hello
argc[1][0] h -> argc[1][4] o
argc[1][1] e -> argc[1][3] l
argc[1][2] l -> argc[1][2] l
argc[1][3] l -> argc[1][1] e
argc[1][4] o -> argc[1][0] h
argc[2] 102
argc[3] [null]
```

Comment: you want to reverse executable file  name also with hello and 102?

Comment: Scan through each argument string, reversing it, and printing the reversed value.  You can modify the argument strings, though it is not always approved of in all programming circles.  Or you can provide storage for the reversed string.  Or you can simply print the characters of the strings in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void print_reversed(const char *str, size_t len)
{
    const char *ptr = str + len;
    while (ptr > str)
        putchar(*--ptr);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
            putchar(' ');
        print_reversed(argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

There's no need to modify the strings; simply print the characters out one at a time in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is fairly straightforward: *For each string in argv, reverse it and then print it.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap_characters(char *s, char *t) {
    char tmp = *s;
    *s = *t;
    *t = tmp;
}

void reverse_string(char *s, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; ++i)
        swap_characters(s + i, s + length - 1 - i);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        reverse_string(argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do string reversal, and it is worth spending some time looking into because it is a standard interview question.

a simple implementation for null-terminated strings in `C` looks like

```
char * reverse(char * string){
  int i;
  int len = strlen(string);
  for (i = 0; i < len/2; i++){
    char c              = string[i];
    string[i]           = string[len - i - 1];
    string[len - i - 1] = c;
  }
  return string;
}
```

This version does manipulate the string, so we'll make a copy of the string just in case.

Once you have string reversal, you will need to run `reverse` on each argument, and print it out.

**NOTE:** arguments in a standard console application like this start with the name of the program as it was typed by the user. So if the program is invoked as `./my-program arg1 arg2`, `argv[0]` will be `"./my-program"`, so we will skip `argv[0]`

Using this, all you have to do is call reverse on each argument. like so

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  int i;
  char * copy;

  for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++){ // skip argv[0]
    copy = strdup(argv[i]); // copy the string;
    copy = reverse(copy);

    printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, copy);

    free(copy); // clean up the copy
  }
}
```

All together, you get

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * reverse(char * string){
  int i;
  int len = strlen(string);
  for (i = 0; i < len/2; i++){
    char c              = string[i];
    string[i]           = string[len - i - 1];
    string[len - i - 1] = c;
  }
  return string;
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  int i;
  char * copy;

  for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++){ // skip argv[0]
    copy = strdup(argv[i]); // copy the string;
    copy = reverse(copy);

    printf("argv[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, copy);

    free(copy); // clean up the copy
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code give File name as reverse and put command line argument:-
[image: May be this will work for you.....]

Comment: Observation: `strrev()` is not a part of the C standard or POSIX.  Where it's available, it is sensible to use it, but it isn't available everywhere.